# SQL HAVING Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, having

Hi I was looking a way to filter an calculated column.
I just fund using HAVING.

I was wondering if with the need to repeat the calculation on having and select, my SQL have to calculate two times and consequently have performance impact.

ie:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
SELECT SalesOrderID, SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING SUM(LineTotal) > 100000.00
ORDER BY SalesOrderID ;
```

Comment: Added the sql-server tag, because this looks a lot like SQL Server.

Comment: Have you compared this query with the same one without the `HAVING`? It should be very simple to verify.

Comment: my current sample database is to small to measure it

Answer (score 2):

The expense in doing the calculation is in arranging the `group by`.  Doing an additional aggregation function adds very, very little overhead compared to arranging the data in groups.  In addition, SQL Server may be smart enough to calculate the `sum()` only once -- I don't know, but it would be a very reasonable optimization.

Note:  this is true of the traditional aggregation functions.  Some, such as `count(distinct)` or the statistical functions incur more overhead and you would want to be more careful about calling them multiple times.

Comment: since Im defining a field name "SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal" there is no way to do something like: "HEAVING SubTotal > 100000.00" ?

Comment: @Flib . . . You can do that in a subquery.  However, it really isn't necessary.  The overhead for an additional aggregation function is miniscule compared to arranging the data in groups.