# Hibernate select new map with where cause

Tags: jquery, hibernate, select

I have an issue about hibernate.  This is an example query about "The Hibernate Query Language"

```
select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n) from Cat cat
```

it is possible to use "as column" in where cause without **native** query ?

```
select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n) from Cat cat 
HAVING max < 50
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is it possible to use `AS` with the `MAP` operator? Yes, it should be possible, is it not working for you? Note that `MAX` and `MIN` are treated as reserved words by some RDBMSes, so sth like `maxBodyWeight` and `minBodyWeight` would probably be a better choice for an alias name

Comment: It's not strictly legal to use an alias in a having clause even in a raw query. what's wrong with using `HAVING max(bodyWeight) < 50`?

Comment: HAVING max(bodyWeight) < 50 is possible but it will be duble time calculation right ?

Comment: It [probably won't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565847/sql-having-performance), but in any case, your query is somewhat... bizarre. You realize that (since there's no `GROUP BY` clause) it will either return a single result or nothing at all, right?

Comment: it is just a simple example.  My query is much more complex.  But looks like it is not support it. 
Thank you for your all comments.